# Return from PHP SVG-image and execute internal javascript via <img> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, svg

There is php-code, which returns svg-image.

```
public function actionJsTest() {
    header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
    $svg = '';
    $svg .= '<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">';
    $svg .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $svg .= '<![CDATA[';
    $svg .= 'alert();';
    $svg .= ']]>';
    $svg .= '</script>';
    $svg .= '<rect x="0" y="0" height="10" width="10" style="stroke-width:1; stroke:black; fill:red"></rect>';
    $svg .= '<circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" fill="red"></circle>';
    $svg .= '</svg>';

    echo $svg;
}
```

When we call php function directly in view, it's work correct and alert fires.

When we use  tag to display that svg from html-page:
`<img src="http://givemesvg.php"/>` - SVG shows correct, but alert will not fire.

Is it a browser security policy or missed something? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images [cannot run script](http://www.w3.org/TR/svg-integration/#secure-animated-mode). That applies equally to the html `<img>` tag, the SVG `<image>` tag and CSS background images.